# I want to make some divs race

Tags: jquery

So maybe this is kind of juvenile, but I'm still learning Jquery. I've got a couple of DIVs (50x50px absolutely positioned) and this code makes them move across the screen.
I want to make it so if you click on the green box it reduces the interval thereby moving faster. Obviously I'm doing something wrong here, I'm just not sure what.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var greenSpeed = 300;
  var redSpeed = 300;
  var redLeft = $('#red').offset().left;
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#red').css('left', ++redLeft);
    }, redSpeed);
  var greenLeft = $('#green').offset().left;
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#green').css('left', ++greenLeft);
    }, greenSpeed);
  $('#green').click(function() {--greenSpeed});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your updates to the timer intervals *after* you've already started the timer will have no effect. Perhaps you should keep the timer interval constant, and then instead of always just adding 1 to the positions, vary the size of the increment.

That is, "redSpeed" and "greenSpeed" would start off at 1, and then you'd add those on each iteration to "redLeft" or "greenLeft".  Clicks should simply increase the "speed" variables by 1 (or 2 or whatever).

Comment: +1. Either clear and reset the interval on each click, or use setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the first one didn't work is that setInterval was being passed the value stored in greenSpeed and not a pointer to that variable.  Because of this, subsequent updates to greenSpeed had no effect.  In your 2nd bit of code, you are calling setTimeout repeatedly.  Each time it is called it is passed the current value stored in greenSpeed, thereby using the new value after a click.

Comment: perhaps that should have been a comment on the previous answer rather than an answer

Answer (score 1):

This works like you want it...

```
$(function(){

    var greenSpeed = 300;
    var redSpeed = 300;

    var redLeft = $('#red').offset().left;

    function raceRed() {

        setInterval(function() {
            $('#red').css('left', ++redLeft);
        }, redSpeed);

    }

    $('#red').click(function() {
        --redSpeed;
        raceRed();
    });

    raceRed();

    var greenLeft = $('#green').offset().left;

    function raceGreen() {

        setInterval(function() {
            $('#green').css('left', ++greenLeft);
        }, greenSpeed);

    }

    $('#green').click(function() {
        --greenSpeed;
        raceGreen();
    });

    raceGreen();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay... so I figured out how to do it, but if someone could explain WHY that would be helpful.

```
var greenLeft = $('#green').offset().left;
function moveGreen() {
    setTimeout(moveGreen, greenSpeed);
    $('#green').css('left', ++greenLeft);
}
moveGreen();
$('#green').click(function() {greenSpeed-=20});
```

My guess is that setInterval only checks `colorSpeed` once when it's first called, so even if I decrement the speed counter it doesn't matter. Is there a way to do it w/ setInterval, or is a recursive setTimeout call the only way?

Comment: It's not so much that it only "checks" the "colorSpeed" values - they're just numbers passed in to the function, so the very existence of the variables is unknown and undetectable by "setInterval()".